# Why component not work?

Tags: ionic2

I am working on ionic 2.0 and AngularJS 2.0, but component "drop-menu" not work.
All codes are in https://github.com/aaronchen2k/test/tree/master/app

tabs.html

```
<drop-menu></drop-menu>
```

dropmenu.js

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'drop-menu',
  templateUrl: 'build/components/dropmenu/dropmenu.html'
})
export class DropMenuComponent {
  constructor() {

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you inspect your code, your component is working, name & image are here.
It's only a problem of css and Ionic tags uses.

Where do you want to display your component ? In tabs row with the 4 others ? In header ? Else ?

Answer (score 0):

Missing directives section

```
@Page({
   templateUrl: 'build/pages/tabs/tabs.html',
   directives: [DropmenuComponent],
   providers: [CategoryService]
})
```